How do I generate a matrix which shows if pairs of elements in a vector are equal
I have a vector in which elements are assigned as either 1 or 0
For example
V1 <- c(1,0,1,1,0)

I want to generate a matrix M of size V1 x V1 in which each element is coded 1 if the values of the vector elements are equal e.g. if V1(1)=1 & V1(3)=1 then M(1,3)=1
In the case above
M = (1,0,1,1,0
     0,1,0,0,1
     1,0,1,1,0
     1,0,1,1,0
     0,1,0,0,1)

My actual matrix will have 44 elements and a will simulate it around 10,000 times  so I need code that runs quickly.
Thanks
Paul
I could code this in a for loop but this would be very inefficient

How come it has 44 elements? Why not 25, 36, 49, ...?

Do you mean 44 elements in the vector V1? Otherwise the matrix has to have a square as its number of elements.

2*tcrossprod(V1 - 0.5) + 0.5. See the benchmarks in my answer.

As you want efficiency, here is an Rcpp solution. I tried getting fancy and using bitwise operations as x[i] == x[j] is equivalent to !(x[i] ^ x[j]) if all values are zeroes and ones, but it wasn't faster than direct comparison. In any case, this may be quicker than outer(). It returns an integer matrix.
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix createMatrix(NumericVector x) {
    int n = x.size();
    IntegerMatrix M(n, n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            M(i, j) = (x[i] == x[j]) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    return M;
}
")

createMatrix(V1)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    0    1    1    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    1    0    1    1    0
# [4,]    1    0    1    1    0
# [5,]    0    1    0    0    1


outer(V1, V1, FUN = \(x, y) as.integer(x == y))

Benchmarks (assuming 44 elements in the input vector):
V2 <- sample(V1, size = 44, replace = TRUE)
bench::mark(
  Andre = +(outer(V2, V2, "==")),
  SB    = outer(V2, V2, FUN = \(x, y) as.integer(x == y)),
  Sam = createMatrix(V2),
  Abin = create_matrix(V2)
)
  expression     min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   memory     time       gc      
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   <list>     <list>     <list>  
1 Andre       18.1µs   20µs    38110.   45.78KB     38.1  9990    10      262ms <int[…]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
2 SB          16.6µs 18.4µs    47984.   45.78KB     52.8  9989    11      208ms <int[…]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
3 Sam            4µs  4.6µs   204136.    7.61KB     20.4  9999     1       49ms <int[…]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
4 Abin        21.8µs 24.5µs    39049.   68.52KB     62.6  9984    16      256ms <dbl[…]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>


Try outer
+(outer(V1, V1, "=="))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    0    1


I recently had to do something similar for a project. :) So, you can approach it in 2 steps basically. First is to have a vectorised way to generate the matrix. And the next step is of course the simulation part.
For creating the matrix, you can use outer function in combination with matrix function. Code below:
V1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
create_matrix <- function(V) {
  M <- outer(V, V, FUN = "==")
  M <- as.numeric(M)
  matrix(M, nrow = length(V), ncol = length(V))
}

M <- create_matrix(V1)

And then for the simulation part, you can use replicate function. Code below:
matrices_10000 <- replicate(10000, create_matrix(V1), simplify = FALSE)

The key part in this is to use vectorisation as much as possible. About outer, you can find more info about it here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/outer

UPDATE
An even faster base solution (see the updated benchmark below):
2*tcrossprod(V1 - 0.5) + 0.5
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    0    1    1    0
#> [2,]    0    1    0    0    1
#> [3,]    1    0    1    1    0
#> [4,]    1    0    1    1    0
#> [5,]    0    1    0    0    1


Two fast options (see benchmarks below).
A fast base solution:
+(tcrossprod(V1 + 1) != 2)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    0    1    1    0
#> [2,]    0    1    0    0    1
#> [3,]    1    0    1    1    0
#> [4,]    1    0    1    1    0
#> [5,]    0    1    0    0    1

A fast Rcpp solution:
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = "
  #include <Rcpp.h>
  using namespace Rcpp;
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  IntegerMatrix v2mat(const IntegerVector& x) {
      const int n = x.size();
      IntegerVector v0 (n);
      IntegerVector v1 (n);
      int n0 = 0;
      int n1 = 0;
      IntegerMatrix M = IntegerMatrix::diag(n, 1);
      
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (x(i) == 1) {
          for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
            M(i, v1(j)) = 1;
            M(v1(j), i) = 1;
          }
          v1(n1++) = i;
        } else {
          for (int j = 0; j < n0; j++) {
            M(i, v0(j)) = 1;
            M(v0(j), i) = 1;
          }
          v0(n0++) = i;
        }
      }
  
      return M;
  }
")

Benchmarking against a couple of the other answers:
V1 <- sample(0:1, 44, 1)

bench::mark(
  outer = +(outer(V1, V1, "==")),
  tcrossprod = +(tcrossprod(V1 + 1) != 2),
  tcrossprod2 = 2*tcrossprod(V1 - 0.5) + 0.5,
  createMatrix = createMatrix(V1), # from @samR
  v2mat = v2mat(V1)
)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 outer          12.6µs   18.9µs    51219.   62.92KB     25.6
#> 2 tcrossprod      6.7µs   14.2µs    69788.   30.78KB     41.9
#> 3 tcrossprod2     2.8µs    6.6µs   149329.   15.56KB     29.9
#> 4 createMatrix    5.8µs      8µs   111447.       8KB     22.3
#> 5 v2mat           4.3µs    6.7µs   140045.    8.05KB     14.0


Brilliant tcrossprod trick,  I love it,+1!

You can use outer + bitwXor for fun
> 1 - outer(V1, V1, bitwXor)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    0    1

or use rep.int
> +(t(V1)[rep.int(1, length(V1)), ] == V1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    0    1

